# Navigation component: Retain same fragment after orientation change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

as I said in the title, I would like to keep my current fragment after rotating the phone. I could actually make it happen by adding

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
```

in the `Manifest`. The problem is that my layout configuration is lost every time.
What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

I'm using `Jetpack Navigation` component. Exist a way to `navigateToCurrentFragment()`?

Edit: Part of onCreate() from Activity()

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    

    val graphInflater = (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mNavHost) as NavHostFragment).navController.navInflater
    val navGraph = graphInflater.inflate(R.navigation.services_nav_graph)

    navGraph.startDestination = R.id.FirstFragment
    (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mNavHost) as NavHostFragment).navController.graph = navGraph

}
```

Comment: this should be supported out of the box as fragment state is retained across orientation changes (you don't need to consume configChanges in manifest), could you please add the snippet from `onCreate()` of your activity?

Comment: Did you use `ViewModel`?

Comment: Yes I use ViewModels